# View file in Filezilla without editing

Tags: filezilla

In Filezilla, you can configure it to "View/Edit" a remote file when double-clicking it.  However, doing so adds it to a list of files you are currently "editing", which means if I try to open the same file again, I get a "Selected file already being edited" prompt asking me if I want to "Reopen local file" or "Discard local file then download and edit file anew".

Whenever I open a remote file, I really want it to make sure I have the latest file (especially when looking through log files).  If it was a big file that I didn't want to download multiple times, I wouldn't be viewing it in such a cavalier, double-click happy manner.

There seem to be some other similar requests: [a feature ticket](http://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/5229) and a [forum post](http://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17377), but they seem a bit neglected.

Is there any way to just "View" a file, rather than "View/Edit"?  This really isn't a huge deal but I don't know if I'm missing something obvious.